# Pass on already deduced type as parameter type for a callback

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction

So I'm trying to do something like the following

```cpp
int x = 123;
myFunction(x, [](auto y) {
    std::cout << y;
});
```

And `myFunction` is defined as

```cpp
template <typename T>
void myFunction(T val, void(*callback)(T)) {
    callback(val);
}
```

When trying to compile the code clang gives me the error `could not match 'void (*)(T)' against '(lambda at ...)'`. I've figured out this is because you can't deduce the type from a lambda.

So that's actually alright because what I actually want is the parameter type of the `callback` to be the type deduced from the `val` parameter of `myFunction`.

So my question put simply is, is it possible somehow to exclude the `callback` parameter from being deduced and instead just use the deduced type of `val`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible somehow to exclude the callback parameter from being deduced and instead just use the deduced type of val?

Sure.

If you define something like this

```
template <typename T>
struct self
 { using type = T; };
```

you can define `myFunction()` as follows

```
template <typename T>
void myFunction(T val, void(*callback)(typename self<T>::type)) {
    callback(val);
}
```

Now `T` is deduced from `val` and used for `callback`.

Starting from C++20, you can avoid the `self` definition and use the newly introduced [`std::type_identity_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity)

```
template <typename T>
void myFunction(T val, void(*callback)(std::type_identity_t<T>)) {
    callback(val);
}
```

Comment: I would probably use `std::type_identity_t<void(T)>* callback`.

Answer (score 1):

One option (and there are a few) is to pass the callable item as a template argument and allow templating to take care of some of the details for you - eg:

```
template <typename T, typename FUNCTOR>
void myFunction(T val, FUNCTOR callback) {
    callback(val);
}

// Note: could be a const ref:
//void myFunction(T val, const FUNCTOR &callback) {


int main()
{

    int some_int{1};
    myFunction(some_int, [](auto y){ std::cout << y << std::endl; });

    float some_float{1.1f};
    myFunction(some_float, [](auto y){ std::cout << y << std::endl; });

    return 0;
}
```

Full example here (following your code - but this could be further tidied): https://godbolt.org/z/qr7T5GPd6

Comment: Thank you. This will for sure work, but the problem is that the callback type will not be known, so the IDE IntelliSense will not know what the type is and can't auto-complete members of the type and so on. @max66 suggestion makes the type known to the IntelliSense.

Comment: @PeterBechP yes, that may well be true! - although I thought there was some template intellisense out (or coming) in the latest vsode/msvs.  I slightly prefer this method, just becuase it is so easy, no refactoring is required (at least in the function template) if you change what you pass in etc... sort of: simplicity + maintainability vs intellisense I guess : )

Comment: Functor way allows capturing lambda :-) (but expected signature is indeed not visible :-/, `std::function` has overhead).